# Create new column across multiple data frames using dfList

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several data frames all with the same colnames. I want to merge two columns in each one of them to create a new column.

data frames looks like this:

[image]

I want the output to look like this:

[image]

Normally I would do this very easily for one data frame:

```
a$XY_ID <- paste(a$X,ak$Y,sep=":")
```

How to do this for all the dataframes in a list?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` command in `lapply` :

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) transform(x, XY_ID = paste(X,Y,sep=":")))
```

In `tidyverse` you can use `map` to iterate over list and `unite` to combine columns.

```
dfList <- purrr::map(dfList, ~tidyr::unite(.x, XY_ID, X, Y, sep = ":", remove = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying your answer but both give errors: tidyverse ```Error in `[.data.frame`(x, x_vars) : undefined columns selected```

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Can you add your data using `dput` instead of image so that we know what is the structure of your data. That error usually mean that we are referring to columns which don't exist in the data. Maybe you have different names of column. BTW I had typo in my first answer which I corrected.

Comment: Tries from scratch and worked. Had too many confusing things in my env. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `do.call` with `paste` and it would also work if there are many columns to concatenate

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) {
         x$XYID <- do.call(paste, c(x[c('X', 'Y')], sep=":"))
         x })
```